# openam ssoadm setup error: Cannot locate system configuration. Directory Server may be down or configuration directory is invalid

Tags: openam, opensso

When we run ssoadm setup script ./setup with SSL(HTTPS) enabled as:

./setup --path /configdir/openam --log /configdir/openam/log --acceptLicense  /configdir/openam/debug -v

ssoadm fails with the following error message:

```
Cannot locate system configuration. Directory Server may be down or configuration directory is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential issues if you get that error message:

1. The config directory server itself is invalid/incorrect. So make sure you are passing the correct config dir to --path (or enter when prompted)
2. If you have SSL enabled, then the certificate needs to be added to your jdk trust store at: $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts store.

Alternatively, you can also modify ./setup as in:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -D"load.config=yes" -D"javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/ssocerts/opensso.jks" -D"javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```